# Second return value of StyleDefinitions in NotebookInformation

Tags: front-end, undocumented

I recently found the wonderful `"StyleDefinitions"` return value from [`NotebookInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookInformation.html) which I've been using to edit style definitions within a notebook itself.

Generally I use this like:

```
First["StyleDefinitions" /. NotebookInformation[EvaluationNotebook[]]]

NotebookObject[$FrontEnd, 84]
```

which returns the stylesheet that I edit programmatically to change my `InputNotebook[]`.

This sometimes has a second return value, though:

```
Last["StyleDefinitions" /. NotebookInformation[EvaluationNotebook[]]]

{NotebookObject[$FrontEnd, 4]}
```

which I don't fully understand.

What does it do?

---

#### Possible explanation

I tend to see this two result form only for stylesheet notebooks:

```
(*Plain nbs*)
nbsdefs =
  ReplaceAll["StyleDefinitions", NotebookInformation /@ Notebooks[]];
Length /@ nbsdefs

{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

(*Stylesheet nbs*)
Length /@
 
 ReplaceAll["StyleDefinitions", 
  NotebookInformation /@ 
   DeleteDuplicates[Cases[Flatten@nbsdefs, _NotebookObject]]
  ]

{2, 2, 2, 2}
```

Where the second argument seems to be the stylesheet notebook it inherits from.

But I'm not certain of this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I am now more certain of my possible interpretation.

For instance, try this:

```
Module[{
  nb =
   CreateDocument[
    Notebook[{
      Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
      Cell[StyleData[
        StyleDefinitions -> 
         FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]]]
      }, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"
     ],
    Visible -> False
    ]
  },
 (NotebookClose[nb]; Lookup[#, "StyleDefinitions"]) &@
  NotebookInformation[nb]
 ]

{NotebookObject[$FrontEnd, 4],
 {NotebookObject[$FrontEnd, 4], NotebookObject[$FrontEnd, 229]}}
```

So the second argument is telling us which stylesheets this stylesheet is inheriting from